# How to insert nested dictionary/json into MySQL table with Python

Tags: python, mysql, json, python-requests, pymysql

I've connected to the https://exchangeratesapi.io/ api like so:

```
import requests, json, pymysql
from db_credentials import db_config

get_url = "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/history?start_at=2018-01-01&end_at=2018-02-02&base=GBP"
response = requests.get(get_url)
results = response.content
data = json.loads(results.decode('utf-8'))['rates']

print(data.keys())
print(data)
```

`data.keys()` and `data` looks like this:

```
dict_keys(['2018-01-22', '2018-01-09', '2018-01-24', '2018-01-03', '2018-01-23', '2018-01-25', '2018-01-18', '2018-02-02', '2018-01-15', '2018-01-02', '2018-01-16', '2018-01-11', '2018-01-17', '2018-01-12', '2018-01-30', '2018-02-01', '2018-01-29', '2018-01-08', '2018-01-10', '2018-01-05', '2018-01-04', '2018-01-26', '2018-01-31', '2018-01-19'])

{'2018-01-02': {'AUD': 1.7327127809,
                'BGN': 2.1986891954,
                'BRL': 4.440996931,
                'CAD': 1.7006733893,
                ...},
 '2018-01-03': {'AUD': 1.730482852,
                'BGN': 2.2064530686,
                'BRL': 4.4264440433,
                ...},
 ...}
```

I have an empty MySQL table with date, currency and rate columns which I'd like to populate with the above using something along the lines of the following code:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(**db_config, cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    insert_statement = "INSERT INTO gbpExchangeRates VALUES (%s)" % data
    cursor.execute(insert_statement)
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Obviously it doesn't work and requires some manipulation beforehand...
I tried `data = json.dumps(data)` but not sure what to do next...

Answer (score 3):

Well you can't simply throw JSON at a database and expect it to work like that. You have to flatten it to rows prepared for insertion.

Take a look at the example I wrote using `SQLite`. It uses the same [DB API v2](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) so it should be fairly compatible with your MySQL driver.

```py
import requests
import json
import sqlite3

get_url = "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/history?start_at=2018-01-01&end_at=2018-02-02&base=GBP"
response = requests.get(get_url)
results = response.content
data = json.loads(results.decode('utf-8'))['rates']

if data:
    conn = sqlite3.connect('rates.db')

    c = conn.cursor()

    # here I simply created an example table containing all the fields you specified above
    c.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE exchange_rates (
            "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            "date" DATE, 
            "currency" TEXT, 
            "rate" NUMERIC
        )
    """)

    c.executemany(
        """INSERT INTO exchange_rates ("date", "currency", "rate") VALUES (?,?,?)""",
        # this is where you iterate over the data and flatten it for SQL
        ((date, currency, value) for currency, value in rates.items() for date, rates in data.items())
    )

    conn.commit()

    conn.close()
```

Comment: Getting duplicated rates for each date and currency

Answer (score 0):

Building on techouse answer.

1. Removed quotes around the column names i.e. date, currency, rate in insert statement
2. Replaced `((date, currency, value) for currency, value in rates.items() for date, rates in data.items())` with `insert_data`

...

```
insert_data = []
for date, rates in data.items():
    for currency, value in rates.items():
        list_data = []
        list_data.append(date)
        list_data.append(currency)
        list_data.append(value)
        insert_data.append(list_data)

insert_data
```